# Highcharts in Django using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, highcharts, django-templates

I am new to Django. I am making polls application and want to use highcharts  to display graphs. I have a template which displays all the polls. I want to show the corresponding results of poll beside it in form of chart. Part of the template:

```
{% for question in poll_questions %}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        {{question.question_text}}
                        {% for choice in question.poll_choices_set.all %}
                        <div>
                            <label><input type="radio" name="{{question.pk}}" value="{{ choice.pk }}">&nbsp {{choice.choice_text}}</label>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div id="{{ question.pk }}" class="chart" style="height: 400px; width: 400px"></div><br>
        <script>
            var question_id = '{{ question.pk }}'
        </script>
        <script src="{% static 'er_interface/polls.js' %}"></script>
    </div>  
{% endfor %}
```

Javascript file- **polls.js:**

```
$.getJSON('/er/poll/'+question_id ,function(data) {
    $('#'+question_id).highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: question_id
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: ':<b>{point.y}</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            },
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function() {
                    return Math.round(this.percentage*100)/100 + ' %';
                    },
                    distance: 0,
                }
            }
        },
        series: data
    });
});
```

The problem is that graph is shown just for the last poll question. Thanks

Comment: Because you're updating the value of `question_id` with every loop. Doing this - `var question_id = '{{ question.pk }}'` in a loop means JS interpreter will read the latest value, *i.e.*, the id of the last question.

Comment: But it is correctly printing data in console from js file. It is just not rendering the chart.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in each of the for loops, `question_id` is overwritten. You might want to do something like this instead:

```
$('.chart').each(function() {
    var that = this;
    var question_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.getJSON('/er/poll/'+question_id ,function(data) {
        $(that).highcharts({
            ...
```

That way, after rendering the page, you loop through each of the `div`s and render the appropriate chart.

Even better: use `data-id="{{ book.id }}"` and retrieve it with `$(this).data('id')` do avoid using the id attribute for something it's not really meant for.

Comment: I had to use question-id to attach chart to div element. 'this' was not working. It was showing  'Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13'. Thanks.

Comment: Ah sorry, went a bit too fast. You indeed lose 'this' inside the callback. Updated the answer, should work now.